# Is NameNode the bottleneck of HDFS throughput?

Tags: hdfs

In HDFS,each read and write have to go through the NameNode to get metaDate about where the data is stored. How does such system scale? Does the NameNode become the bottleneck of the entire system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namenode does become a bottleneck, but not that easily that it appears to be. The Namenode holds the metadata, once a client say for read gets the block locations from the Namenode, it doesn’t need to go to namenode for reading, it would connect to the datanodes directly for reading without NN intervention.
As for a Write, the client does go to Namenode first to create an entry in Namespace tree, then to get datanodes where to write the data, once it has the datanode locations, it would be talking to the Datanodes only, it will go back to Namenode only when it needs another block. So, for most of the time the client would be with datanodes only, it would go to Namenode for very small amount of time.

The read calls at Namenode(say getting block locations) all are processed in parallel, it’s the write calls only which aren’t  processed in parallel(like getting a new block to write). In normal productions usually the Read load is more around 60:40 so this does scale and work well.

In the recent additions there is one more category of Namenode called the Observer Namenode, which can serve all Read requests, and there can be N number of Observer Namenodes in the cluster...

If you want to read about Observer Namenodes, Can read here :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ObserverNameNode.html

Comment: So NameNode is a bottleneck ,just not easy to reach it。I wander is there a threshhold which HDFS become usable if the write opearation rate exceed ?

Comment: yes, when would it reach bottleneck that depends upon the machine on which it is running, the memory and vCores etc. There is no specific values or a specific math formula that can tell, this many write/read calls and resources at NN will make it bottleneck. The Namenode response time shall increase as the load increases, but it won't die. The bottleneck can not only come in case of load, since the all the metadata is in Namenode's heap memory, if there are too many files, In general case more than 500-600M in that case as well the namenode will start giving problems..